# Select rows based on criteria from within group

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have the following table:

```
pk_positions    ass_pos_id   underlying   entry_date
1               1            abc          2016-03-14
2               1            xyz          2016-03-17
3                            tlt          2016-03-18
4               4            ujf          2016-03-21
5               4            dks          2016-03-23
6               4            dqp          2016-03-26
```

I need to select one row per `ass_pos_id` which has the earliest `entry_date`. Rows which do not have a value for `ass_pos_id` are not included.

In other words, for each non null `ass_pos_id` group, select the row which has the earliest `entry_date`

The following is the desired result:

```
pk_positions    ass_pos_id   underlying   entry_date
1               1            abc          2016-03-14
4               4            ujf          2016-03-21
```

Comment: what if there are 2 rows for a given ass_pos_id that have the same earliest entry date?

Comment: hi. The nature of the application that uses this data ensures that this scenario will never happen. ie: this is taken care of outside of the database. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `row_number` window function:

```
SELECT pk_positions, ass_pos_id, underlying, entry_date
FROM   (SELECT pk_positions, ass_pos_id, underlying, entry_date,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ass_pos_id
                                  ORDER BY entry_date ASC) rn
        FROM   mytable
        WHERE  ass_pos_id IS NOT NULL) t
WHERE   rn = 1
```